# How to count the number of elements in an extremely large lazy seq?

Tags: memory, clojure, out-of-memory, large-data, lazy-sequences

I have the following (extremely large) `lazy-seq`:

```
(def lazy-list (partition-all 100000 (take 10000000000000000000 (repeat 1))))
```

I want to count the number of elements in it, for which I am doing the following:

```
(time
  (loop [ll lazy-list
         c 0]
    (if-not (seq (take 1 ll))
      c
      (recur (drop 1 ll)
             (inc c)))))
```

If I run this I get the following error:

```
Execution error (OutOfMemoryError) at user/eval2043$fn (REPL:1).
Java heap space
```

But if I am not holding the `head` anywhere, why am I seeing this `OOM` issue?

Answer (score 5):

*But if I am not holding the head anywhere ... ?* The head of the sequence is held by `lazy-list`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a slightly different version and it worked:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [obj (vec (repeat 100000 2)) ]
    (loop [ll (repeat 1e8 obj)
           cnt 0]
      ; (spyx (type ll)) ; first is "clojure.lang.Repeat", rest are "clojure.lang.LazySeq"
      (if-not (seq (take 1 ll))
        (spyx cnt)
        (recur (drop 1 ll)
               (inc cnt))))
    ))
```

with result

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.3    Java 17
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
cnt => 100000000

Ran 2 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.

Passed all tests
Finished at 11:42:52.954 (run time: 10.706s)
```

Going back to your example, I tried:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(def take-item (take 1e7 (repeat 1)))
(def lazy-list (partition-all 1e4 take-item ))

(dotest
  (spyx (type take-item))
  (spyx (type lazy-list))

  (time
    (loop [ll lazy-list
           c 0]
      (if-not (seq (take 1 ll))
        (spyx c)
        (recur (drop 1 ll)
               (inc c)))))
)
```

with result

```
-------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.3    Java 17
-------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
(type take-item) => clojure.lang.LazySeq
(type lazy-list) => clojure.lang.LazySeq
c => 1000
"Elapsed time: 2787.211076 msecs"

Ran 2 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.

Passed all tests
Finished at 11:50:42.880 (run time: 2.811s)
```

But note that `take-item` is holding on to the head of the 10 million long list of ones. I suspect that is your problem.

The moral of the story is that lazy sequences are sometimes useful, but are tricky and easy to get wrong.  Then are not a miracle, can often cause unexpected bugs, and I prefer to always use concrete vectors whenever possible.

I'd recommend to only use a lazy sequence if there is no other choice possible.